# Python scrapy multiple crawlers

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

i have problems with scrapy running multiple crawlers. What i want to achieve:

I have an engine running in the background taking tasks/jobs from the mysql database. Every 15 seconds the mysql db is queried. If there is a new job scrapy should process it.

My setup is working fine so far - the last problem is, that my spiders (scrapy spiders) get "stacked" in the CrawlerRunner.

Start:

```
def schedule():
    jobs = GetJob.Job()
    jobs.getJobs()

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    t = task.LoopingCall(schedule)
    t.start(15)
    reactor.run()
```

After GetJob.Job() the Jobs will be processed here:

```
class ProcessJob():
    def processJob(self, job):
        #update job
        mysql = MysqlConnector.Mysql()
        db = mysql.getConnection()
        cur = db.cursor()
        job.status = 1
        update = "UPDATE job SET status=1 WHERE id=" + str(job.id)
        cur.execute(update)
        db.commit()
        db.close()
        #Start new crawler
        webspider = MySpider.MySpider(job)   
        #Some settings
        ajaxSettings = CrawlerSettings.ajax_settings
        normalSettings = CrawlerSettings.normal_settings
        configure_logging()
        if job.max_pages != 0:
            ajaxSettings["CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT"] = 0
            ajaxSettings["CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT"] = job.max_pages
            normalSettings["CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT"] = 0
            normalSettings["CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT"]  = job.max_pages 

            #max connections
            concurrent_requests = int(job.max_pages / 20)
            if concurrent_requests < 1:
                concurrent_requests = 10
            if concurrent_requests > 500:
                concurrent_requests = 500
            ajaxSettings["CONCURRENT_REQUESTS"] = concurrent_requests
            normalSettings["CONCURRENT_REQUESTS"] = concurrent_requests


        #Ajax true or false
        if job.ajax == 1:
            runner = CrawlerRunner(ajaxSettings)
        else:
            runner = CrawlerRunner(normalSettings)

        d = runner.crawl(webspider, job=job)
```

And here is my spider:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):          

def __init__(self, job):               
    #Get the hosts
    self.job = job
    dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
    allowedDomainsPre = job.url.split(",")
    allowedDomains = []        
    for domains in allowedDomainsPre:
        parsed_uri = urlparse(domains)
        domain = '{uri.netloc}'.format(uri=parsed_uri)
        print domain
        allowedDomains.append(domain)

    self.allowed_domains = allowedDomains
    self.start_urls = allowedDomainsPre
    #Get job patterns
    jobPatterns = job.processing_patterns.split(",")
    allowedPatterns = []
    deniedPatterns = []
    for pattern in jobPatterns:
        if '-' in pattern:
            deniedPatterns.append(pattern.replace("-", ""))
        else:
            allowedPatterns.append(pattern)        

    self._rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(allowedPatterns), deny=(deniedPatterns)), callback=self.parse_items, follow=True)
            ]    
    self.name = job.id   
    self.settings = CrawlerSettings.normal_settings

def spider_closed(self, spider):
    stats = spider.crawler.stats.get_stats()
    itemCount = 0
    try:
        itemCount = stats["item_scraped_count"]
    except:
        print "Item count = zero"      
    DoneJob.DoneJob().jobDone(self.job, itemCount)

def parse_items(self, response):           
    item = Item()
    #if the user wants a minimum description
    if self.job.min_description > 0:            
        item['html'] = response.body  
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['job_id'] = self.job.id
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'html.parser')        
        article = Document(soup.prettify()).summary()
        article_soup = BeautifulSoup(article) 
        text = re.sub(' +', ' ', article_soup.get_text().rstrip())
        text_length = len(text.split(' '))            
        if text_length > self.job.min_description:
            return item
    else:
        item['html'] = response.body  
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['job'] = {}
        #Job
        item['job']['id'] = self.job.id
        item['job']['user_id'] = self.job.user_id
        item['job']['name'] = self.job.name
        item['job']['url'] = self.job.url
        item['job']['api'] = self.job.api
        item['job']['max_pages'] = self.job.max_pages
        item['job']['crawl_depth'] = self.job.crawl_depth
        item['job']['processing_patterns'] = self.job.processing_patterns
        item['job']['days'] = self.job.days
        item['job']['ajax'] = self.job.ajax
        item['job']['min_description'] = self.job.min_description           
        return item
```

So after running two or three jobs my spider_closed get called multiple times instead of (expected) once.

So what is wrong here?